# List all subgroup elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ that contains $8$ and $12$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Problem : List all subgroup elements of $\mathbb{Z(*,+)}$ that contains $8$ and $12$.

My solution is :
$\mathbb{Z}_{13}$ since it contains $8$ and $12$, and then of course $\mathbb{Z}_{13 + k}$ where $k$ are natural numbers. Is that all?

But the main question is i dont know whats the meaning of "all subgroup elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ ", its from my abstract algebra exam. My solution above is my interpretation of it.

Comment: I can't be certain, but my guess is that you are being asked for the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ which contain both $8$ and $12$. The subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ are all infinite cyclic groups. Your examples are not, though they could be quotient groups of $\mathbb{Z}$.  So think about what elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ could generate a subgroup that contains both $8$ and $12$.

Comment: Over this zone of the galaxy, and when dealing with stuff related to the group (or ring) of integers, the *usual* meaning is $\;\Bbb Z_{13}:=\Bbb Z/13\Bbb Z\;$= the group (ring) of residues modulo $\;13\;$ , so: (1) how in the world did you come up with your solution??, and (2) under the above agreement, $\;\Bbb Z_{13}\;$ is not a subgroup of $\;\Bbb Z\;$ .

Comment: If you're considering $\mathbb{Z}(\cdot,+)$, that is a *ring*, not a *group*; $\mathbb{Z}(+)$ would be a group. I'm not quite sure what a "subgroup element" is supposed to be either.

Answer (score 0):

There are in fact some subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ that contain both $8$ and $12$, for example $\mathbb{Z}$ as a subgroup of itself. But there is a smallest one, namely the subgroup generated by the gcd of $8$ and $12$, $$4 \mathbb{Z}$$.

Other subgroups are $\mathbb{Z}$ and $2\mathbb{Z}$. Are there any more? ;-)